# Identificar idioma utilizando o pacote franc

Tags: r

Não consigo escrever o código para que o pacote `franc` identifique o idioma dos dados da planilha. Este é o repositório do pacote: https://github.com/MangoTheCat/franc

O código a seguir não me fornece o resultado desejado:

```
library(franc)
teste_franc <- read_excel("/teste-franc.xlsx")
head(teste_franc)
franc(teste_franc)
```

Ele lê apenas a frase e indica a tradução.

Como ler os dados de uma planilha e identificar seu idioma?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: `teste_franc` é um data.frame, não é uma string, a função `franc` tem um vetor `"character"` de comprimento 1 como entrada.